# Коментарии к алгоритму Си

Tags: c

Недавно я искал алгоритм вычисления самого длинного слова в строке, и я его нашел! Создал функцию и все работает хорошо, вот собственно она:

```
void the_longest_word(char *str){
    int l, ml = 0, iw = 0; 
   char *mw = 0, *c = str, *w;  
   while (*c) { 
     if ( !iw && isalpha(*c) ) { 
       iw = l = 1; 
       w = c; 
     } else if ( iw && isalpha(*c) ) { 
       l++; 
     } else if ( iw && !isalpha(*c) ) { 
       if (l > ml) { 
         mw = w; 
         ml = l; 
       } 
       iw = 0; 
     } 
     ++c; 
   } 
   if (mw) { 
     *(mw + ml) = 0; 
     printf("%s", mw); 
   }
}
```

Но так как я новичок, естественно я ничего не понял xD.
Может кто то прокомментировать этот код, вы мне очень поможете!
Заранее огромное спасибо!)

Comment: Учитесь читать код!

Comment: Для чего же я еще попросил помощи?

Comment: Ну так читайте - и задавайте вопросы по кускам кода, где и что не понятно. Хотя для Вас лучше потыкаться там отладчиком и разобраться, представленный код элементарен)

Comment: Элементарен для вас. Я же сказал что я абсолютный новичок. Я просто хотел его понять (алгоритм), попробую сделать сам тогда) Спасибо за ответ

Comment: Книжка Керниган-Ричи, совсем не толстая

Answer (score 2):

Сори за орфографию и пунктуацию

```
void the_longest_word(char *str)
{
    int l, ml = 0, iw = 0; 
    // l - длина текущего слома 
    // ml - длина самого длинного слова 
    // iw - флаг показывающий была ли последняя итерация внутри слова или нет
    char *mw = 0, *c = str, *w;  
    // с - итератор символов 
    // w - первый символ текущего слова 
    // mw - первый символ самого длинного слова 
    while (*c)//начинаем цикл прохода по всем символам строки 
    { 
        if ( !iw && isalpha(*c) ) //если мы не внутри слова(были) и текущий символ часть слова. Это условие истинно, когда мы нашли 1 символ слова
        { 
            //устанавливаем переменные
            iw = l = 1;
            w = c; 
        } else if ( iw && isalpha(*c) ) // если мы внутри слова(были) и текущий символ часть слова. Это условие истинно, когда мы идём по символам внутри слова
        { 
            l++; // увеличиваем длину на 1
        } else if ( iw && !isalpha(*c) ) // если мы внутри слова(были) и текущий символ не часть слова. Это условие истинно, когда мы только вышли из слова
        { 
            if (l > ml) //если длина текущего слова больше максимального найденого. Это условие истинно когда мы нашли самое длинное слово из всех прошедших
            { 
                //запоминаем параметры самого длинного слова
                mw = w; 
                ml = l; 
            } 
            iw = 0; // обнуляем флаг, показывая что мы вышли из слова
        } 
     ++c;//идём на следующий символ
   } 

   //!!!DANGER!!! СЛЕДУЮЩИЕ КОМАНДЫ ИЗМЕНЯЮТ ИСХОДНУЮ СТРОКУ

   if (mw) //если мы нашли ходь одно слово - выводим его на экран
   { 
     *(mw + ml) = 0; //!!! ставим символ конца строки в ячейку после самого длинного слова
     printf("%s", mw); //выводим строку начиная с символа самой длинного слова
   }
}
```